# I am trying to check if my Input has a lower or uppercase letter in it:

Tags: c#, string, uppercase, lowercase

I am trying to check in C# if the input I type has a uppercase letter or a lowercase letter and specify how many lower and uppercase letters there are. The 'Input' is the string length of the input that you type in, and 'letters' is a string array letters a - z lowercased.

The first two statements check if 'Input' contains a lowercase letter and else if 'Input' contains a lowercase letter, they both seem to work, but it can't check them both for some reason:
The final else if statement checks if the input has at leas 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase:

```
for(int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++) 
{
    if(Input.Contains(letters[i].ToLower()))
    {
        WriteLine("Lowercase");
    }
    else if (Input.Contains(letters[i].ToUpper()))
    {
        WriteLine("Uppercase");
    {
    else if (Input.Contains(letters[i].ToLower()) &&
        Input.Contains(letters[i].ToUpper()))   
    {
        WriteLine("Uppercase and Lowercase");
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of checking like this , you can use ascii characters. it will be better. share your sample input string.

Comment: Something Like "Hello World"

Comment: Input and letters both are same or different ?

Comment: Input would be what you would type in, and letters is an array that contains letters a through z as a string

Comment: What does `1` count as? `%`?

Comment: `var lowerCount = letters.Count(char.IsLower);` ? I'm guessing you can figure out the rest

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method that iterates over the characters in the string and maintain a counter for upper/lower case characters using the `char.IsUpper` and `char.IsLower` Methods.

```
(int,int) CheckCase(string value)
{
    var countUpper = 0;
    var countLower = 0;
    foreach(var c in value)
    {
        if(char.IsUpper(c)) 
        {
            countUpper++; 
        }
        else if(char.IsLower(c)) 
        {
            countLower++; 
        }
    }
    
    return (countUpper,countLower);
}
```

As observed, this would need only a single iteration of the characters in the string.

You could now use the method as

```
var (countUpper,countLower) = CheckCase("SampleString");
```

With the count of uppercase and lowercase characters in hand, you could now implement your logic of display

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly better ways to do this. But the reason what you currently have doesn't work is because if the last condition is ever true, then so is the first condition. So the first `if` block will always be the one to execute in that case. To fix what you have, you should move the last condition to be first:

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++) 
{
    if (Input.Contains(letters[i].ToLower()) &&
        Input.Contains(letters[i].ToUpper()))   
    {
        WriteLine("Uppercase and Lowercase");
    }
    else if (Input.Contains(letters[i].ToUpper()))
    {
        WriteLine("Uppercase");
    {
    else if(Input.Contains(letters[i].ToLower()))
    {
        WriteLine("Lowercase");
    }
}
```